# Make cannot match the target

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I am working on my first makefile, so far this much done.

```
BUILD = build
BIN = bin
OUTPUTNAME = game.out
INCLUDE = /internalLibraries/include

SRCFILES := $(wildcard src/*.cpp) 
OBJFILES := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRCFILES))
OBJFILES := $(foreach dir,$(OBJFILES),$(subst src/,,$(dir)))
DIR := $(dir $(OBJFILES))

$(foreach d,$(DIR),$(shell mkdir -p $(BUILD)/$(d)))
$(shell mkdir -p $(BIN))

CC = g++ 
CFLAGS  = -g -std=c++11
LIBS=-lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system


G++_VER_LT48 := $(shell expr `$(CC) -dumpversion | cut -f1-2 -d.` \< 4.8 )
ifeq ("$(G++_VER_LT48)","1")
$(error old version of g++ not supported, upgrade to 4.8 or higher)
endif


default: $(BIN)/$(OUTPUTNAME)

$(info $(OBJFILES))
$(BIN)/$(OUTPUTNAME): $(BUILD)/$(OBJFILES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(BIN)/$(OUTPUTNAME) $(BUILD)/main.o $(BUILD)/game.o $(BUILD)/food.o $(BUILD)/snake.o $(LIBS)


$(BUILD)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ -I $(INCLUDE)
```

the problem is, running this produces the output:

```
sidhin@DRAGONHEART:/mnt/c/Users/sidhi/Desktop/Projects/sfml-snake$ make
food.o game.o main.o snake.o
make: *** No rule to make target `build/food.o', needed by `bin/game.out'.  Stop.
```

What is the problem, I cannot make it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(BUILD)/%.o: %.cpp
```

With `BUILD` set to "build", this specifies the rule for building a target called "build/food.o" from "food.cpp".

The problem is, obviously, that "food.cpp" does not exist. The actual source file is "src/food.cpp", based on your declaration:

```
SRCFILES := $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
```

Comment: And the fix could be to change the pattern rule to: `$(BUILD)/%.o: src/%.cpp`